# extract table values form curl output

Tags: bash, curl, awk, sed, echo

I'm trying to extract random values that proceed a unique string, the layout is

```
<tr><td><a>uniquestring"</a></td>
<td>RANDOM NUMBER k/b</td>
<td>RANDOM NUMBER</td>
<td>RANDOM NUMBER</td>
<td>RANDOM NUMBER</tr>
```

I want to do something like

```
curl -is http://webpage.com/ |grep uniquestring | echo RANDOM NUMBER k/b
```

I'd also like to return all values on a single line ie echo

```
uniquestring RANDOMNUMBER k/b RANDOMNUMBER RANDOMNUMBER RANDOMNUMBER
```

The page generates multiple 'blocks' of 5 the lines above and i'm only interested in obtaining the values that are after a specific uniquestring.

Comment: The fact that the output comes from `curl` isn't really relevant. What you want is some way to parse HTML from `bash`. `echo` isn't really relevant, and neither `awk` nor `sed` are suitable for parsing HTML.

Comment: `cat input | grep -A 5 uniquestring | perl -ne 's|<[^<]+?>||g; chomp; print $_ . " ";'`

Comment: that worked great thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all values on single line

```
curl -s webpage.com | grep -A 5 uniquestring | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

To just return RANDOM NUMBER k/b

```
curl -s webpage.com | grep -A 1 uniquestring | grep -v "uniquestring" | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr -c '@(skip)
<tr><td><a>@uniq"</a></td>
<td>@num1 k/b</td>
<td>@num2</td>
<td>@num3</td>
<td>@num4</tr>
@(output)
@uniq @num1 k/b @num2 @num3 @num4
@(end)' - < data
eb09b744e3e914d67f86a1fee82e9002634ac 123098340 k/b 4949848 9648 334938
```

Here we match as much of the structure as possible, including the static piece of text `k/b`. It is assumed that the unique string is variable; we don't know what it is and want to extract it.

The sample `data` file contains:

```
$ cat data
<tr><td><a>eb09b744e3e914d67f86a1fee82e9002634ac"</a></td>
<td>123098340 k/b</td>
<td>4949848</td>
<td>9648</td>
<td>334938</tr>
```